# git - extract some files into shared 'lib'

Tags: git, libraries

There were some similar projects (projA and projB), which was developed separately and had similar files in it. No VCS was used.

After time, some 'library' (let's call it `lib` directory) same for both projects was developed. And git usage was started.

Now, I can't understand, what git functionality I have to use to? Submodule? Subtree? Something else?

The task is: track `lib` separately. But use it for `projA` , `projB` and other projects. And I want to 'git' older files of projects, where there were no separate `lib`. This need to support different versions of `projA` and `projB` - how it can be done with git? If possible - with some examples.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If `lib` is something used both by `projA` and `projB` I would make it a separate git repository to handle just `lib` changes, storing its history independently from anything else.

Then in `projA` and `projB` you would need to include `lib` in some way but that will mostly depends on how the projects are developed and deployed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, tracking separately is a variant. And then build whole project with some 'build' script. But `lib` isn't full independent software - it's simply some code same for all projects. If I will track it separately - some time I will get confused in versions of projects and `lib' -this I'm afraid of.

Comment: It is not a problem if `lib` is not an independent software, it can be its own repository. The other way would be to have only one repository, and having `lib`, `projA`, and `projB` as separate directories in the repository, or if really useful git submodules but I think that these offer more drawbacks than benefits. As for the problem of versions, during deployment, `projA` and `projB` can specify the specific commit of the `lib` git repository that they should use (or better, use git tags inside `lib` repository)

Comment: Thanks again. Well, same thoughts I have. But was thinking there're more elegant ways in git to work with 'shared libs'...